# Back to top link inserts additional code to URL

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using a back to top class in the footer of my page that looks like this

```
<div class="top"><a href="#main"><img src="images/back-top.png" alt="back-top" /></a> </div>
```

When you click it my URL changes to

```
 www.mysite.com/#main
```

instead of

```
 www.mysite.com
```

Is there a way to make "#main" not appear in the URL once the back to top link is clicked?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why would you use "#main" into your href? in the case you use that attribute as any kind of identifier of the element i recommend you to put it in the id, the class or an invented attribute like attr="#main". About the #main in the url you could use href="javascript:;".

Comment: Sory, i havent undertand it well :B, you could use href="javascript:window.scrollTo(0, 0)".

Comment: Thanks Jiancerouno Taringa!

Answer (score -1):

If you have Jquery script included on your site. You can use this simple [JQuery plugin](https://bytutorial.com/framework-and-scripts-library/backtotoplink-jquery-plugin) to help creating the back to top link easily.